# React Native reported Dimensions wrong/different to browser-reported dimensions

Tags: ios, react-native, safari, screen-resolution, attribution

I'm trying to create a signature for web-to-mobile user-attribution purposes.

I'm on an iPhone 14 Pro and I'm trying to look at screen resolution as a criteria, but the reported values seem to differ across browser (Safari) and React Native.

I'm doing the following on web:

```
alert(`${window.outerWidth}x${window.outerHeight}x${window.devicePixelRatio}`)
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

And this React Native code:

```
import { Dimensions  } from 'react-native'

const { width, height, scale } = Dimensions.get('window') // same with `get('screen')`
Alert.alert(`${width}x${height}x${scale}`)
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

Why is there this difference here? Which one is the true screen resolution and how can I get the two to match? Thanks.

EDIT: This issue is not iOS-specific apparently. It spans across OS/Vendors.

Android (Samsung):
[image]

Android (Huawei):
[image]

Comment: I didn't.. there's no source of information whatsoever on this

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. If i have any info i will let you know